# Mostrar Indicados Indiretos abaixo dos Diretos

Tags: php, html, laravel

Como faço Para poder mostrar os Indiretos dos meus Indicados Diretos?
No caso da imagem, este é meu Indicado Direto porém a baixo dele tem uns Indiretos. De forma Alguma estou conseguindo resolver, Alguém p dar uma luz?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue um trecho do meu PHP

```html
    public function getIndicados($id = '') {

        if ($id == '') {

            $id = Auth::user()->id;

        }

        $reffer = Referrals::where('pai_id', $id)->get();



        $users = array();



        foreach ($reffer as $key => $r) {

            $users[$key] = $this->where('id', $r->user_id)->first();

        }



        return $users;

    }



    public function getFilhos($id = null, $count = false) {

        if (!$id) {

            $id = $this->id;

        }



        $reffer = Referrals::where('system_id', $id)->orderBy('direcao', 'ASC')->get();



        $users = array();



        foreach ($reffer as $key => $r) {

            $user = $this->where('id', $r->user_id)->first();

            $user->direcao = $this->getUserDirection($r->user_id);

            $users[$key] = $user;

        }



        if ($count) {

            return count($users);

        }



        return $users;

    }
```

E Meu HTML

```html
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Nome</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Telefone</th>
      <!-- <th>DireÃ§Ã£o binÃ¡ria</th> -->
      <th>SituaÃ§Ã£o</th>
      <th>Investimento</th>
      <th>GraduaÃ§Ã£o</th>


    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @inject('usuarios', 'App\User') @foreach($usuarios->getIndicados() as $user)
    <tr>
      <td><b>{{$user->name}}</b></td>
      <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->telefone}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->getStatus()}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->getPacote()->nome}}</td>
      <td>{{$user->minhaGraduacao()}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ao que se refere Indireto e Direto, não entendi o que seria cada um

Comment: Seria os referidos dos referidos ex: vc se cadastrou e recebeu um link referral, desse link outra pessoa pessoa se cadastra e fica em baixo de vc lhe dando comissão, mas neste caso ja está tdo pronto, só quero realmente que mostre quem esteja abaixo do meu referido

Comment: No caso a imagem, esta pessoa esta abaixo de mim, porem ela tem outra abaixo dela que n está aparecendo